# can anyone solve this Error: can't read the block: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When starting the

> **e2e_cli**

of the fabric, I appear the error

> Error: can't read the block: &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}

just as shown in the figure.
Has anyone encountered such a problem? I need help......... x(

the Reported error
[image]

Comment: Does the orderer node started correctly?. Check it with `docker container logs orderer.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the port 7050 of the Orderer was not exposed. Try to do a telenet on the Orderer port:

`telnet IP PORT`